# Incorrect IF Decision in C# - Zed Graph Out of Range Error - RollingPointPairList

Tags: exception, zedgraph

This is really mind-boggling. I am using RollingPointPairList of Zed Graph, and I kept getting an error saying Argument Out of Range. So I decided to use the source code of Zed Graph instead of .dll files. I can now see where the exception is thrown. But I am totally perplexed to see why.

This is where the exception is thrown:

Original code from RollingPointPairList:

```
public PointPair this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index >= Count || index < 0)
            {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
            index += _tailIdx;
            if ( index >= _mBuffer.Length )
                index -= _mBuffer.Length;

            return _mBuffer[index];
        }
```

Surprisingly, index was never greater or equal to count, or less than 0.

I modified the code to see what was really going on like this:

```
if (index >= Count || index < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(index + " " + Count);
                Console.Beep(5000, 1000);
                if (index >= Count || index < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
```

So I did hear the beep, and it did output something, but this time did not reach the throw excpetion, because of the second if check.

Here is what I see on the output:

[image: Output]

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

P.S. I have made sure that multiple threads do not try to modify RollingPointPairList

Comment: How are you feeding input to this? I mean the index.

Comment: It's a code from the ZedGraph Library. Interesting, let me check how it is modified.

Comment: Also the second if check is same as first if check so it should throw exception right? If you can hear a beep then you should also get exception.

Comment: That's the dilemma, it does not throw an exception. So it passes through the first IF, but not the second IF. It's like the value ofindex changed somehow by the time it got to the second IF.

Comment: Is Count a property? If yes, what is the code for getter for that?

Comment: I'm not too good with interfaces, but I believe Count is a property inherited from IPointPair, in which it is defined as follows:

int Count { get; }

It looks like it's calling itself.

Comment: The interface has just the definition. You need to check the the PointPair class which inherits the interface and provides the body for Count property. Is it changing based on some condition?

Comment: There is nothing about Count in PointPair, but there is this in the same class (RollingPointPairList) ......................
.........................................

  public int Count
  {
   get
   {
    if ( _headIdx == -1 )
     return 0;

    if ( _headIdx > _tailIdx )
     return ( _headIdx - _tailIdx ) + 1;

    if ( _tailIdx > _headIdx )
     return ( _mBuffer.Length - _tailIdx ) + _headIdx + 1;

    return 1;
   }
  }